# How create table automatically with liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I need to create separate tables in DB for every month, each table should has year and month in its name, like:

table_name_2023_1,
table_name_2023_2,
table_name_2023_3,
....
table_name_2023_12

Such table I need by demand, at the beginning of each year, table should be created for full year.

Can I achieve this with liquibase?

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase doesn't do this out of the box, but you could implement a CustomChange to encapsulate this logic. https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/custom-change.html

Or you could move the logic outside Liquibase and use a property. https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html

Comment: I believe this is easily achivabale. every time you can read the time and date from your DB, then based on that check which tables are there and which are missing. then you can add whats missing. for the rollback, you can delete all the tables you created based on a pattern name that you like.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wrote procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createTablesForPeriod(replacement varchar(64), sqlScript varchar(10000), startDate DATE, monthFromCurrentDate INT)
BEGIN
          SET @Start_Date = startDate;
          SET @End_Date = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL monthFromCurrentDate MONTH);

          WHILE(@Start_Date < @End_Date) DO
              SET @datePart = DATE_FORMAT(@Start_Date, '%Y_%c');
              SET @query = REPLACE(sqlScript, replacement, @datePart);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
SET @Start_Date = DATE_ADD(@Start_Date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
END WHILE;
END
//
```

And also I created such create table template:

```
SET @create_table_query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF 
  NOT EXISTS `my_tabe_name_%yyyy_mm%` (
  ....fields here
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;');
```

And then I call it with parameters:

```
CALL `createTablesForPeriod`('%yyyy_mm%', @create_table_query, STR_TO_DATE('1,4,2023','%d,%m,%Y'), 12);
```

Last script I added in separate migration changeSet with flag  `runAlways="true"`

Update:
Also it is possible to [create customChange task](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/custom-change.html) with all this logic in java class